# Flask, python dictionary to highcharts JS figure

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, highcharts, flask

I have a flask web-application. In this application I call "bar.htm"

`return render_template('bar.htm', mapping=mapping)`

where mapping is a dictionary like:

`mapping = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}`

Now I want to use this dictionary in a Highcharts bar graph. Where the bar graph with example data looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/

(link to code to prevent huge question)

How can I implement my own dictionary in this JS file?
datasection for highchart graph is like:

`series: [{
    name: 'Population',
    data: [`<- this is where the variable`mapping` should come
        `['Shanghai', 23.7],
        ['Lagos', 16.1],
        ['Instanbul', 14.2],
        ['Karachi', 14.0],
        ['Mumbai', 12.5],
        ['Moscow', 12.1]
]`

Comment: have you used `mapping|tojson|safe` in your jinja2 template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Python view:

```
mapping = [
    ['Shanghai', 23.7],
    ['Lagos', 16.1],
    ['Instanbul', 14.2],
    ['Karachi', 14.0],
    ['Mumbai', 12.5],
    ['Moscow', 12.1],
    ['Sao Paulo', 11.8],
    ['Beijing', 11.7],
    ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
    ['Delhi', 11.1],
    ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
    ['Seoul', 10.4],
    ['Jakarta', 10.0],
    ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
    ['Tianjin', 9.3],
    ['Tokyo', 9.0],
    ['Cairo', 8.9],
    ['Dhaka', 8.9],
    ['Mexico City', 8.9],
    ['Lima', 8.9]
]
return render_template('page.html', mapping=mapping)
```

And the HTML:

```
...
series: [{
    name: 'Population',
    data: {{ mapping|safe }},
    dataLabels: {
        ...
```

Define `mapping` as a list of lists, and then pass it to the template, using the `safe` filter.

Comment: Thank you, the `|safe` is what i missed!

Comment: I have learnt that its safer to use JSON to send the data instead of sending the python data structure directly to avoid issues like [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537282/javascript-syntax-error-in-django-template-when-variable-value-is-missing).  
Also, @Henkes and Celeo, does the above answer mean that its not really possible to pass a dict as series to Highcharts? We'll always have to send it as a list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can use objects as data points, but you cannot use custom names. It should be something like {y:10, name: 'yourname'}. So only what you need is use your mapped objects in correct structure.

Comment: correct structure? What do you mean by correct structure? I use the dictionary for the key and value, {'Jack':4098} where Jack is the label like Shanghai in the example. Do you mean that it is not possible to cast my dictionary to this JavaScript file?

Comment: But you need to have stricture {y:4098} not custom field name

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by no custom field name? 'shanghai', 'lagos' and ' Instanbul' are also custom stings right?

Comment: Replace {'Jack':4098} with {'y':4098}

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for. I don't want 'y' as a label on my dataset. I want 'Jack' on my label. and the height on my bar should be 4098. If i make it {'y':4098} I will have no idea to what person 4098 is linked.

Comment: See my answer again, you can use y param and name, then you will have sort of "relation"

Comment: Please enlighten me on how such a dictionary should look like, I tried this in python with a dictonary which looks like: `dict = {'y':10, 'name': 'yourname'}`
and got an empty graph.
'y' without quotes or 'name' without quotes results in a python error

Comment: Well, defauly it should work like here: http://jsfiddle.net/vdvuag4u/ so ensure if you have array of points objects, and types are correct.

Comment: well yes, If I insert the dictionary in the javascript code it works. but if i cast this object from my flask page to the javascript graph and use the name of the object in the data section. nothing happens.
And please note that i cannot insert this data manually. the dataset changes every time.

Comment: Im sorry but Im not experienced with flask.

Comment: Well, it's not a flask specific problem. I sent a dictionary to a HTML page which I can read through in the following way:
`{% for key, value in mapping.iteritems() %}
   <tr>
        <th> {{ key }} </th> 

        <td> {{ value }} </td>

   </tr>
{% endfor %}`
Now instead of printing these values in a table, i want to inser these values in the Javascript graph. so this object called `mapping` should be loaded into the graph. I can edit mapping to this way: ` dict = {'y':10, 'name': 'yourname'}` the only problem then is, loading it in the graph